# PHP $_GET Returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a url in which i am trying to extract some parameters.
My URL can have two forms, 
Either 'Code' or 'Refresh'
But it returns null, even thought the url the parameters are set
URL --> **WITH 'CODE'** http://www.example.com/token.php?client_id=hello&client_number=blahblah&type=authcode&code=hello23423

URL --> **WITH 'REFRESH'** http://www.example.com/token.php?client_id=hello&client_number=blahblah&type=authrefresh&refresh=74388bye

```
$token = "NULL";
$client = $_GET['client_id'];
$secret = $_GET['client_number'];
$type = $_GET['type'];

if (isset($_POST["code"])) {
    $token = $_GET['code'];
}

if (isset($_POST["refresh"])) {
    $token = $_GET['refresh'];
}

echo $client;   // $client, $secret and $type is printed without any issues
echo $secret;
echo $type;
echo $token;  <---- Always returns NULL even though the URL has the parameters CODE or REFRESH
```

Comment: `isset($_POST["code"])`? Why `post`? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing `$_GET` and `$_POST` (these are not interchangeable).

When you're passing parameters in a query string you will always use `$_GET`:

```
if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
    $token = $_GET['code'];
}

if (isset($_GET["refresh"])) {
    $token = $_GET['refresh'];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `$_REQUEST` in alternative to `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

http://php.net/manual/it/reserved.variables.request.php

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST e $_COOKIE.

Comment: This would mean that the code in the question would work, however, if the OP is only using query strings to pass the data then there isn't really any point. This seems more like a workaround when there's a clear fix.

Comment: Agree! Just wanted to share this possibility for him to avoid confusion using one method to retrieve all parameters received. Was better to just add it as a comment to the question. Sorry about that, :)

Comment: Using request is very risky in terms of security

Comment: @Akintunde oops. why is that? didn't know

Answer (score 0):

you have to understand when to user `$_GET` and `$_POST`

`$_GET` used when you pass parameter by query string(In url)(also when you set form method get)

`$_POST` Information sent from a form with the POST method

in your case you are pass data using query string so you have to check data is set or not by `$_GET` rather than `$_POST`

```
if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
    $token = $_GET['code'];
}

if (isset($_GET["refresh"])) {
    $token = $_GET['refresh'];
}
```

if you still confuse use `$_REQUEST` it's support both passed parameter by query string (GET) and also POST

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
        $token = $_REQUEST['code'];
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST["refresh"])) {
        $token = $_REQUEST['refresh'];
    }
```